# Remote attribute doesn't hit the action controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to use remote attribute validation in Asp.net-core 2.2, but i don't hit the action method inside the validation controller.

These scripts are provided

```html
    <script src="~/site/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/site/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/site/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Validation controller

```
    [Authorize]
    public class ValidationController : Controller
    {
        [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
        public IActionResult ValidateDupliciteName(string name)
        {
            var test = false;

            return Json(test);
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
    [Remote("ValidateDupliciteName", "Validation")]
    public string name { get; set; }
```

And the view for model binding i am using knockout.

```html
<input type="text" class="input-validation-error form-control" data-bind="value: @(nameof(Model.name))" />
```

I don't get any error messages, when i set breakpoint inside the action method it doesn't get hit. 
The problem might be that when i open developer tools in chrome i don't see any url request to the validation controller action method...

Answer (score 1):

For Remote validation attribute, it uses with code below

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
```

it will generate the similiar html during rendering the view.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-remote="'Name' is invalid." 
  data-val-remote-additionalfields="*.Name" data-val-remote-url="/Validation/ValidateDupliciteName" 
  id="Name" name="Name" value="">
```

For your code, it doesn't contain this code, and `knockout` will not generate the remote related html code.

If you prefer knockout, you need to implement your own request with ajax, and you could refer [Validation / Remote Validation with knockout.js in vb.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521427/validation-remote-validation-with-knockout-js-in-vb-net-mvc)

Comment: Thank you that was exactly the problem !

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have form element in your view. Name property must be within form element.
You also have to the following part in your view;

```
 @section Scripts {        
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
    }
```